# jquery datetimepicker restrict time in datetime picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery datetime picker as follows:-

```
$('.DatePickerWithTime').datetimepicker({
    ampm: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:mm TT',
    stepMinute: 15
});
```

I want to set a minimum date and time for it.

If i set it using following:-

```
$('.DatePickerWithTime').datetimepicker({
        ampm: true,
        timeFormat: 'h:mm TT',
        stepMinute: 15,
        minDate: minimumDate,//some date in date time format
        maxDate: maximumDate//some date in date time format
    });
```

the date part works ok but the time part doesnot work

thanks

Comment: What plugin are you using for the datetimepicker? As far as I know, the official jQueryUI only has a datepicker.

Comment: it is the timepicker plugin from trentrichardson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) it looks like you just need to change the options from Date to DateTime:

```
$('.DatePickerWithTime').datetimepicker({
    ampm: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:mm TT',
    stepMinute: 15,
    minDateTime: minimumDate, //some date in date time format
    maxDateTime: maximumDate  //some date in date time format
});
```